# run a query code to retrieve array from database without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Am kind of not into ajax or json requests, but it seems i might be needing it now or any alternative means, am working on a school management software, i have a page with forms in which when i select a class on the form, it loads all subjects attributed to the class from the database, i already have a php code that would query that, but since php is a server-side language, i would have to reload the page to get the list of subjects from the selected class.. please how can i go about it using any means; here is my code to get classes based on class selected into an array... how can i make this run without a reload

$subjects = $this->crud_model->get_subjects_by_class(class_id);

Comment: I think the tutorial you want to look for is jquery :) It will let you send a request to a snippet of PHP code that will fetch you the data - which you can return via a JSON or other manner and then have your javascript handle the data to populate the form as needed.

Comment: You'll have to make an effort and look up some examples yourself, there are tons of questions about ajax around here - so you're on the right track, that's what you'd probably have to use. Refer jquery's ajax function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic ajax call:

```
<script>   

 $('#button').click( function () {

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "phpsite.php",

                data: {

                    postdata: variable 

                },
                success: function(data){
                    $('#divtochange').html(data);


                }
            });
        } );

</script>
```

In phpsite.php, just put the code you would usually refresh. You will need to include jQuery.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)